# http-server booting unidentified response and garbled body

Tags: macos, httpserver

Booting a server with http-server command results in an unidentified response before crashing with a load of gabled characters. This happens regardless of what directory I'm making this command, even an empty folder.

Versions of various things I'm using:
npm 8.3.0
node v17.30.0
macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

What are the troubleshooting steps I would take for resolving this?

[Response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3AsD.png)

[Re-installed http-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTDK9.png)

Comment: Maybe read the documentaiton and provide a little more detail:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server  Is that what you are using ?

Comment: yes that's what I'm using.

Comment: The problem is caused by a dependency: https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/285#. The maintainer defaced its package and that's causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Update] issue was resolved by completely uninstalling my http-server module:

which http-server - > directory

remove directory

and reinstalling http-server with brew rather than npm....

I later found this which is an exact replica of the issue I was seeing https://snyk.io/blog/open-source-npm-packages-colors-faker/, the npm install must be using the vulnerable method of colors@1.4.1 where as brews version doesn't use it.

http-server maintainers are aware of this and working to resolve it.